# How to format the output of GroupBy in a Dataset

Tags: dataset

Suppose I have a dataset

```
titanic = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
   Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd05e.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This two `Groupy` will give a output like

```
titanic[GroupBy["class"], GroupBy["sex"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But actually I'd like a format like

[image]

How to get a `Dateset` with such structure?

Comment: What do you expect to be in the empty cells?  Also, the result of the first `GroupBy` does give you `result["1st", "female", "age"]` for all ages of that class and gender.

Comment: What code did you use to make the last image? And why doesn't that code satisfy you?

Comment: @Edmund It keep empty still

Comment: Should be `result["1st", "female", All, "age"]`

Comment: @m_goldberg I have updated the structrue what I'm after. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't how there can be any values under "female" and "male". And you didn't answer my question on how you made the image you are showing.

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't sure you mean [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIG3N.png) or not,which is made by *Excel*.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, there are only two ways to present the dataset under grouping by class and sex. They are these.

Class dominant

```
grped1 = titanic[GroupBy["class"], GroupBy["sex"]];
new1 = Map[KeyDrop[#, {"sex", "class"}] &, grped1 // Normal, {3}];
ds1 = Dataset[new1]
```

[image: ds1]

Sex dominant

```
grped2 = titanic[GroupBy["sex"], GroupBy["class"]];
new2 = Map[KeyDrop[#, {"sex", "class"}] &, (grped2 // Normal), {3}];
ds2 = Dataset[new2]
```

[image: ds2]

I do not know why Mathematica formats the 1st case differently from the 2nd case, and I do not know any way to make it format the 1st case like the 2nd case.